# How is date encoded/stored in MySQL?

Tags: c++, mysql, date, encoding, mysql-x-devapi

I have to parse date from raw bytes I get from the database for my application on C++. I've found out that date in MySQL is 4 bytes and the last two are month and day respectively. But the first two bytes strangely encode the year, so if the date is 2002-08-30, the content will be 210, 15, 8, 31. If the date is 1996-12-22, the date will be stored as 204, 15, 12, 22.
Obviously, the first byte can't be bigger than 255, so I've checked year 2047 -- it's 255, 15, and 2048 -- it's 128, 16.

At first I thought that the key is binary operations, but I did not quite understand the logic:

```
2047: 0111 1111 1111
255:  0000 1111 1111
15:   0000 0000 1111

2048: 1000 0000 0000
128:  0000 1000 0000
16:   0000 0001 0000
```

Any idea?

Comment: Here's what the MySQL documentation says, which is not consistent with what you report that you found out: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/date-and-time-data-type-representation.html

Comment: I used MySQL C++ connector to select a row from a table, and these 4 bytes are what I get when I call getRawBytes() to check out which data matches the date. This documentation is the first thing I read to find an answer, but I didn't understand what is '×16×32' in 'A three-byte integer packed as YYYY×16×32 + MM×32 + DD' and why did I got what I got.

Comment: Exactly the same problem unsolved
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68884182/interpreting-mysql-connector-c-field-values-raw-4-bytes-to-a-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you provide, it seems to be `N1 - 128 + N2 * 128`.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue and developed the following C++20 helper methods for production use with mysqlx (MySQL Connector/C++ 8.0 X DevAPI) to properly read DATE, DATETIME and TIMESTAMP fields:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>
#include <chrono>
#include <mysqlx/xdevapi.h>

namespace mysqlx {

static inline std::vector<uint64_t>
mysqlx_raw_as_u64_vector(const mysqlx::Value& in_value)
{
  std::vector<uint64_t> out;

  const auto bytes = in_value.getRawBytes();
  auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<const std::byte*>(bytes.first);
  auto end = reinterpret_cast<const std::byte*>(bytes.first) + bytes.second;

  while (ptr != end) {
    static constexpr std::byte carry_flag{0b1000'0000};
    static constexpr std::byte value_mask{0b0111'1111};

    uint64_t v = 0;
    uint64_t shift = 0;
    bool is_carry;
    do {
      auto byte = *ptr;
      is_carry = (byte & carry_flag) == carry_flag;
      v |= std::to_integer<uint64_t>(byte & value_mask) << shift;

      ++ptr;
      shift += 7;
    } while (is_carry && ptr != end && shift <= 63);

    out.push_back(v);
  }

  return out;
}

static inline std::chrono::year_month_day
read_date(const mysqlx::Value& value)
{
  const auto vector = mysqlx_raw_as_u64_vector(value);
  if (vector.size() < 3)
    throw std::out_of_range{"Value is not a valid DATE"};

  return std::chrono::year{static_cast<int>(vector.at(0))} / static_cast<int>(vector.at(1)) / static_cast<int>(vector.at(2));
}

static inline std::chrono::system_clock::time_point
read_date_time(const mysqlx::Value& value)
{
  const auto vector = mysqlx_raw_as_u64_vector(value);
  if (vector.size() < 3)
    throw std::out_of_range{"Value is not a valid DATETIME"};

  auto ymd = std::chrono::year{static_cast<int>(vector.at(0))} / static_cast<int>(vector.at(1)) / static_cast<int>(vector.at(2));
  auto sys_days = std::chrono::sys_days{ymd};

  auto out = std::chrono::system_clock::time_point(sys_days);

  auto it = vector.begin() + 2;
  auto end = vector.end();

  if (++it == end)
    return out;
  out += std::chrono::hours{*it};

  if (++it == end)
    return out;
  out += std::chrono::minutes{*it};

  if (++it == end)
    return out;
  out += std::chrono::seconds{*it};

  if (++it == end)
    return out;
  out += std::chrono::microseconds{*it};

  return out;
}

} //namespace
```

Which can then be used as follows:

```
auto row = table.select("datetime", "date").execute().fetchOne();
auto time_point = read_date_time(row[0]);
auto year_month_day = read_date(row[1]);
```

---

[getBytes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-cpp/8.0/classmysqlx_1_1abi2_1_1r0_1_1_row.html#aeb0c3821b9b1a259ae61bf8bab0b9221)   document links to `ColumnMetaData` document url.

[ColumnMetaData](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/structMysqlx_1_1Resultset_1_1ColumnMetaData.html)  document links to protobuf encoding url.

[protobuf encoding url / Protocol Buffers Documentation](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/encoding/)   Documentation say :

> **Base 128 Varints**
>
> Variable-width integers, or varints, are at the core of the wire
> format. They allow encoding unsigned 64-bit integers using anywhere
> between one and ten bytes, with small values using fewer bytes.
>
> Each byte in the varint has a continuation bit that indicates if the
> byte that follows it is part of the varint. This is the most
> significant bit (MSB) of the byte (sometimes also called the sign
> bit). The lower 7 bits are a payload; the resulting integer is built
> by appending together the 7-bit payloads of its constituent bytes.
>
> So, for example, here is the number 1, encoded as `01` – it’s a single
> byte, so the MSB is not set:
>
> ```
> 0000 0001
> ^ msb
> ```
>
> And here is 150, encoded as `9601` – this is a bit more complicated:
>
> ```
> 10010110 00000001
> ^ msb    ^ msb
> ```
>
> How do you figure out that this is 150? First you drop the MSB from
> each byte, as this is just there to tell us whether we’ve reached the
> end of the number (as you can see, it’s set in the first byte as there
> is more than one byte in the varint). Then we concatenate the 7-bit
> payloads, and interpret it as a little-endian, 64-bit unsigned
> integer:
>
> ```
> 10010110 00000001        // Original inputs.
>  0010110  0000001        // Drop continuation bits.
>  0000001  0010110        // Put into little-endian order.
>  10010110                // Concatenate.
>  128 + 16 + 4 + 2 = 150  // Interpret as integer.
> ```
>
> Because varints are so crucial to protocol buffers, in protoscope
> syntax, we refer to them as plain integers. 150 is the same as `9601`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the logic of encoding is to erase the most significant bit of the first number and to write the second number from this erased bit like this:

```
2002 from 210 and 15:

1101 0010 -> _101 0010;
0000 1111 + _101 0010 -> 0111 1101 0010

2048 from 128 and 16:

1000 0000 -> _000 0000
0001 0000 + _000 0000 -> 1000 0000 0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version???

`DATETIME` *used to be* encoded in packed decimal (8 bytes).  But, when fractional seconds were added, the format was changed to something like

- Length indication (1 byte)
- `INT UNSIGNED` for seconds-since-1970 (4 bytes)
- fractional seconds (0-3 bytes)

`DATE` is stored like `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED` (3 bytes) as days since 0000-00-00 (or something like that).

How did you get the "raw bytes"?  There is no function to let you do that.  Select HEX(some-date) first converts to a string (like "2022-03-22") then takes the hex of it.  That gives you `323032322D30332D3232`.

Answer (score 0):

About Code refrence the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74126571/7707781).

About document content check below words :

[getBytes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-cpp/8.0/classmysqlx_1_1abi2_1_1r0_1_1_row.html#aeb0c3821b9b1a259ae61bf8bab0b9221)   document links to `ColumnMetaData` document url.

[ColumnMetaData](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/structMysqlx_1_1Resultset_1_1ColumnMetaData.html)  document links to protobuf encoding url.

[protobuf encoding url / Protocol Buffers Documentation](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/encoding/)   Documentation say :

> **Base 128 Varints**
>
> Variable-width integers, or varints, are at the core of the wire
> format. They allow encoding unsigned 64-bit integers using anywhere
> between one and ten bytes, with small values using fewer bytes.
>
> **Each byte in the varint has a continuation bit that indicates if the
> byte that follows it is part of the varint.** This is the most
> significant bit (MSB) of the byte (sometimes also called the sign
> bit). The lower 7 bits are a payload; the resulting integer is built
> by appending together the 7-bit payloads of its constituent bytes.
>
> So, for example, here is the number 1, encoded as `01` – it’s a single
> byte, so the MSB is not set:
>
> ```
> 0000 0001
> ^ msb
> ```
>
> And here is 150, encoded as `9601` – this is a bit more complicated:
>
> ```
> 10010110 00000001
> ^ msb    ^ msb
> ```
>
> How do you figure out that this is 150? First you drop the MSB from
> each byte, as this is just there to tell us whether we’ve reached the
> end of the number (as you can see, it’s set in the first byte as there
> is more than one byte in the varint). Then we concatenate the 7-bit
> payloads, and interpret it as a little-endian, 64-bit unsigned
> integer:
>
> ```
> 10010110 00000001        // Original inputs.
>  0010110  0000001        // Drop continuation bits.
>  0000001  0010110        // Put into little-endian order.
>  10010110                // Concatenate.
>  128 + 16 + 4 + 2 = 150  // Interpret as integer.
> ```
>
> Because varints are so crucial to protocol buffers, in protoscope
> syntax, we refer to them as plain integers. 150 is the same as `9601`.

**Each byte in the varint has a continuation bit that indicates if the byte that follows it is part of the varint.**