# How to read DATETIME with MySQL C++ Connector 8.0 with ISO 8601 format

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I want to read `DATETIME` with MySQL C++ Connector 8.0 with ISO 8601 format.
I have read lots of examples, but all of them seems to be too complex and some of them won't work. Such this one is very complex and seems to be to much code and very unstable.
Is there any better way to read `DATETIME` if `DATETIME` contains microseconds?

[Interpreting mysql connector c++ field Value's raw 4 bytes to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68884182/interpreting-mysql-connector-c-field-values-raw-4-bytes-to-a-date/74126419#74126419)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is.

Here is the code. `DATETIME` is intepreted as the data type `RAW`.

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> getDatabaseValues(const char tableName[]) {
    std::vector<std::string> values;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> table;
    if (isConnectedToDatabase()) {
        // Select only the first row
        std::string query = "SELECT * FROM " + std::string(tableName);
        mysqlx::SqlResult result = connection->sql(query).execute();
        int columnCount = result.getColumnCount();
        if (result.hasData()) {
            mysqlx::Row row;
            while (row = result.fetchOne()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                    switch (row[i].getType()) {
                    case mysqlx::common::Value::UINT64:
                        values.push_back(std::to_string(row[i].get<uint64_t>()));
                        break;
                    case mysqlx::common::Value::INT64:
                        values.push_back(std::to_string(row[i].get<int64_t>()));
                        break;
                    case mysqlx::common::Value::FLOAT:
                        values.push_back(std::to_string(row[i].get<float>()));
                        break;
                    case mysqlx::common::Value::STRING:
                        values.push_back(row[i].get<std::string>());
                        break;
                    case mysqlx::common::Value::RAW:
                        mysqlx::bytes data = row[i].getRawBytes();
                        const mysqlx::byte* first = data.begin();
                        int lengthOfData = data.length();
                        switch (lengthOfData) {
                        case 10: // DATETIME(6)
                            int year = (first[1] << 7) | (first[0] & 0x7f);
                            int month = first[2];
                            int date = first[3];
                            int hour = first[4];
                            int minute = first[5];
                            int second = first[6];
                            int microsecond = (first[9] << 14) | (first[8] << 7) | (first[7] & 0x7f);
                            char text[20];
                            sprintf(text, "%i-%i-%i %i:%i:%i.%i", year, month, date, hour, minute, second, microsecond);
                            values.push_back(text);
                            break;
                        }
                        
                        
                    }
                }
                table.push_back(values);
                values.clear();
            }
        }
    }
    return table;
}
```

Here is the theory

[image]

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/group__MY__TIME.html#datetime_and_date_low_level_rep

Comment: @Fyx Yes. Saving it for later if I forgot my code.

Comment: @Fyx Reading date time seems to be a very common question here at SO. But no one have solved like I just did.

Comment: Ok, but were you meant to edit your question or answer it?

Comment: @Fyx Answering it. Just so I remember it in the future.

Comment: @Fyx, It's legit to answer one's own question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Yes, I was confused about that at the start but then realised. Thanks for the clarification.